# Recoding multiple answers into the same variable in R

Tags: r

Before I ask my question I just want to let you know Im not trying to reinvent the wheel here. For a school assignment I need to recode answers from a question in a dataset into two categories "Christian" and "Not Christian". Because there are multiple phases of christianity, I just need them all in one variable. In the data set, there are 15 answers that would qualify someone as Christian and 5 that would not. I thought adding commas between the numbers would work,

```
CES.df$religion[CES.df$religion== 1,2,4,5,7,9,10,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,20] <- "Christian"
```

That gives me an error which says there is an incorrect amount of subscripts. Could anyone give me a hand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `%in%` instead of `==` as `==` does elementwise comparison and is applicable only if the `length` of the vector to be compared in `rhs` is either 1 (recycling happens) or of the same length as the `lhs` object

```
CES.df$religion[CES.df$religion %in% 
       c(1,2,4,5,7,9,10,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,20)] <- "Christian"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I ran the code and it still says "Incorrect number of subscripts, any idea what that might be because?

Comment: @letsgetthismoney sorry, there is a syntax issue that i overlooked.  It should be vector with `c(...)` updated